In the 18th century Letters of Recommendation were used as a means of introduction. Was there anything equivalent used in 17th century Europe?
Benjamin Franklin wrote many such letters for people wanting to travel to the US when he served as ambassador in Paris .
I have not found any reference to such letters in the 17th century. When a noble, regent, or member of the merchant class was traveling to a new city for the first time would they have such a letter or other means of introducing themselves to those in power in the city?
While I'm most interested in 17th century Netherlands any answer discussing western Europe at the time would be helpful.

Gerónimo Paulo de Manzanares, a Spanish writer published in the year 1600 Estilo y formulario de cartas familiares, segun el gouierno de Prelados, y Señores temporales (Style and form of family letters, according to the government of Prelates and Temporal Lords), a manual about how to write letters.
And one of the chapters of the manual is about:

Letters of recommendation to commend people who aspire to government positions (Cartas de recomendacion para encomendar a personas que pretenden cargos de gobernación).
Letters to commend business, and make profits in them (Cartas para encomendar que favorezcan negocios, y hagan gracias en ellos).
Letters of recommendation to commend beneficial business (Cartas de recomendacion para encomendar negocios de beneficios).
Letters of recommendation to commend lawsuits and trials (Cartas de recomendacion para encomendar pleitos, y la justicia y breve despacho de ellos)
Letters of recommendation on disputes and doubts (Cartas de recomendacion sobre diferencias y questiones).
Letters of recommendation to introduce people and make sure they are attended as they deserve (Cartas de recomendación para dar a conocer personas y que les den favor en lo que se les ofreciere).
Letters of recommendation to accompany others written by other people (Cartas de recomendacion para acompañar otras escritas por otras personas en la misma conformidad).

I think the point 6 is exactly what you were asking about.

I am wondering about the "cartas familiares". Does that mean this is only a guide for introducing family members, or only people to family members, or is the word used in the sense English uses "familiar" (well-known)? My spanish dictionary also lists desenfadado, casual, as a possible use case.

It is exactly the information I was looking for. Thank you.

@ccprog I don't know why it says "familiares". I've checked the book and he doesn't explain it. It could mean the senses you said (family members, casual and well-known), but also "in good spirits".

I think I found a hint. Towards the end of the Prologo, the author says: "porque estas son mas para Escritura, do non solo familiar, sino doctamente se presentende ensenar cosas politicas, o espirituales, que para escrivir familiarmente", roughly translating to: "Unlike a familiar letter, Scripture is more about teaching poliotics and religion". From that antagonism, "personal letter" might point in the right direction

Nice answer. But what would be the difference between "negocios" (business) in #2, and "negocios de beneficios" (beneficial business) in #3?

@SJuan76 Number 3 is about investing businesses and loans. Businesses where the person only risks money, not their work.
